# Can angular momentum be transported between scales in turbulent flows?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, viscosity, navier-stokes, turbulence

Consider a turbulent rotating flow. You are interested in its average features so you use the Reynolds-averaged Navier-Stokes equation. Now, conservation of angular momentum implies the viscous stresses are symmetric. But isn't that valid only for the *total* flow? In other words, is it possible that there could be a situation where there is transfer of angular momentum from, say, the large scales to the small scales? Could the angular momentum of the large-scale flow be "dissipated" into the turbulent eddies? Would that result in antisymmetric Reynolds stresses?